# CAS Server setup

Tags: 8, users, authentication-authorization

I have setup a Drupal 8 with CAS configurations - https://dev.cas.local

Here is the configuration:

- **Version:**  2.0 or higher
- **Hostname** dev.cas.local
- **Port** 443
- **URI** /cas
- **SSL Verification** Verify using web server's default certificates.
- **Login Link Enabled** checked *CAS Log in*
- *Gateway* Feature is disable
- *Forced Login* is disabled
- *USER ACCOUNT HANDLING* is disabled
- *LOGOUT behaviour*  is disabled

Now, in a different site (http://dev.cas-site-one.local) which have the same configuration. Now when I try to login to **cas-site-one** it redirects me to https://dev.cas.loca/cas/login?service=http%3A//dev.cas-site-one.local/casservice which gives a 404.

Comment: What does **CAS** stand for?

Comment: Central Authentication Service

Comment: make your site https

Comment: Do both the server and the client need to be using https?